# Estimate location from GSM mobile network

Tags: geolocation, gsm

I've a GSM module with me. And I'm also uing a GPS module with it . (Both with arduino)

I want to ask is there a way to estimate my location from my GSM mobile network. I don't want any precise location but only like in which state I'm or so.
I know it's not a programming related question but if anyone has any idea then it will be good.

Answer (score 0):

From GSM you get the current GSM-cellID where you are currently booked in. then you have too look up that cellId in a DB which then delivers you the location.
The company SkyHook provides such a service, that e.g Apple's iphone uses.

A list of public cellID Data bases can be found here: 
[Public CellID Databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_ID)